# Changing context does not update the mu4e-main buffer

Tags: mu4e, email

I managed to set up mu4e with two accounts, however I'm having issues switching context.

I press `;` and select the context I wish, and I can also see in the modeline that the context has changed. However on the main buffer it still displays the previous context, and I need to manually restart mu4e in order for the new context to appear.

Is there any way to set up so that changing context also updates mu4e-main buffer?

This is the setup I have atm

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e")
(require 'mu4e)

(setq
    mue4e-headers-skip-duplicates  t
    mu4e-view-show-images t
    mu4e-view-show-addresses t
    mu4e-compose-format-flowed nil
    mu4e-date-format "%y/%m/%d"
    mu4e-headers-date-format "%Y/%m/%d"
    mail-user-agent 'mu4e-user-agent
    mu4e-change-filenames-when-moving t
    mu4e-context-policy 'pick-first
    mu4e-attachments-dir "~/Downloads")

(setq mu4e-bookmarks
  '(( :name  "Inbox"
      :query "maildir:/INBOX/"
      :key ?i)
    ))

(setq mu4e-contexts
      `(,(make-mu4e-context
           :name "home"
           :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Entering Home context"))
           :leave-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Leaving Home context"))
           :vars '((user-mail-address . "mc@personal.com")
                   (user-full-name . "mc")
                   (mu4e-maildir . "~/mail-home/")
                   (mu4e-sent-folder . "/Sent/")
                   (mu4e-trash-folder . "/Trash/")
                   (mu4e-mu-home . "~/.mu-home")
                   (mu4e-sent-messages-behavior . 'sent)
                   (mu4e-get-mail-command . "mbsync -a Home")
                    
         ))
        ,(make-mu4e-context
           :name "work"
           :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Entering Work context"))
           :leave-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Leaving Work context"))
           :vars '((user-mail-address . "mc@work.com")
                   (user-full-name . "mc")
                   (mu4e-maildir . "~/mail-work/")
                   (mu4e-mu-home . "~/.mu-work/")
                   (mu4e-sent-folder . "/[Gmail]/Sent Mail/")
                   (mu4e-trash-folder . "/[Gmail]/Bin/")
                   (mu4e-get-mail-command . "mbsync -a Work")
                   (mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
                   ))
        ))

;; ask for account when composing mail
(setq mu4e-user-mail-address-list
      (mapcar (lambda (account) (cadr (assq 'user-mail-address account)))
              marcc/mu4e-account-alist))
```